# Is it a good idea to enable --inspect for nodejs in production (kubernetes)?

Tags: node.js, debugging, kubernetes, remote-debugging, production-environment

I have a nodejs pod running in kubernetes production environment. Additionally there is staging and review environment in the same cluster running the same app. I recently added --inspect to the start command in the dockerfile which gets deployed to all environments.
My question is, if I enable debugging in production as well, will it impact performance or memory usage? Is it a good practice in general? Otherwise I'll need to create a separate dockerfile for production.

Comment: When you are using kubernetes, you could just overwrite the command, without having a seperate docker file ...

Answer (score 4):

> will it impact performance or memory usage?

Both probably negligiable if just having the flag enabled, mileage may vary if actually live debugging.

> Is it good practice

I would say no, and it does have [security implications](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#security-implications). Although, this would only be a problem if you were to set a public IP, by default debugging would only be permitted on the localhost.

My.advice would be create a separate Dockerfile for prod.

Answer (score 2):

While not doing any of the above, you can always enable the debugger by sending a signal to the process without restarting the application:

`kill -usr1 ${PID}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Rookout](https://www.rookout.com). It's a platform that lets you debug your code while in production, without stopping the runtime - and it also supports Kubernetes.

Basically, you install the Rookout SDK by installing its npm package:

```
npm install --save rookout
```

or (if you're using yarn)

```
yarn add rookout
```

Then, just initiate the sdk in your code with the token you're provided:

```
const rookout = require('rookout');

rookout.start({
    token: 'YOUR_ROOKOUT_TOKEN'
});
```

Then just redeploy your app, and you'll never have to redeploy again to debug. You can just log into the Rookout Web IDE and then you'll be able to place non-breaking breakpoints to get whatever data from your code that you need.

Also, it's important to note that using Rookout has little to no performance impact. In terms of performance, it's pretty much the same as setting a `console.log` statement; hardly noticeable.

Comment: Looks like a useful tool -- and from searches, I also found several others like it (Lightrun, NerdVision, Thundra, etc.). However, in my case I'm most interested in getting memory/heap snapshots of my NodeJS app (running in k8s pod), because the Chrome dev-tools keeps disconnecting (for some reason) whenever I try to take a heap, allocation, etc. snapshot. Do you know if any of these tools support tracing memory allocations and such?

Comment: @Venryx Rookout does support tracing as well as monitoring, and also has profiling tools in place.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find docs on actually using the profiling tools (eg. Agile Flame Graphs). I messaged Rookout support, and got: `After checking with our engineering team, we don't currently have support (or docs) for the profiling capability with Node.js at this time. I can drop you an email in the future if the team prioritizes that feature, but [...] it depends on having tracing (OpenTelemetry/OpenTracing) within your application.` They do apparently have that tool for (I think) Python, but even there, no docs yet, and behind a feature flag. The tool does look quite nice though!

Answer (score 0):

Figured a better solution.
Create a wrapper script which enables debugging only for non-production environments. For production if it is absolutely necessary, it is better to manually exec into pod and debug.
Here is the script: `start.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$ENVIRONMENT" = "production" ] ;then
 npm start;
else
 npm run debug;
fi
```

and in the dockerfile,

```
CMD [ "/app/src/start.sh" ]
```